# Writing style in React and Redux about using store or connect()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im new to React and have a question about the writing style for React.
The question is that when geting state from redux , which is better or  normal writing style.

1) using connect() and mapPropsToState() *react-redux
2) using store and getState()

Now Im using 'connect()' because many tutorials use 'connect()' to pass or get state from Redux.
But I think if these components have children , Props have to be passed into children like without using Redux.

It is killing one of redux's strong point that can get state from any layer(anywhere).

sample code her

*index.js*

```
export let store = createStore(reducer);
<Provider store={store}>
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route component={parent}>
  </Route>
</Router>
</Provider>
```

*render.js*

```
class parent exteds react.Component{
 render(){
 return(
   <child test={this.props.test}/>
  )
 }
}

class child exteds react.Component{
 render(){
  return(
    <button onChange={this.props.test}/>
       or
    <store.dispatch(testfunction()>

   )
  }
 }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
console.log(state)
return {...state};
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return bindActionCreators({
    test:testfunction
}, dispatch)
};

export const renderFormGenerator = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(render);
```

Comment: You can use `connect` in the children too.

Comment: thanks for a reply!  It means it can be used if not passed into children componet?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can use `connect` in any component to access redux state and pass it to component's `props`.

Comment: Thanks. In my code, when not passing props into children, the error message show up, like  'this.props.test is not function' so I thought it have to be passed into children too. Maybe there is some bug in my code so i will check them out.

Answer (score 1):

As your application grows it will be better to use **react-redux** ,over manually  passing **store** to all of your individual components.

That said , there is a small change required in your `connect` . The component that you wish to received your action creators should be in the place of your `render`

i.e Instead of this

`connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(render)`

do this

`connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(myComponent)`

This way you can access your action creators in myComponent like `this.props.myAction()`

I agree with your concern that if it is used this way , you will have to manually pass the action again as props to the children .

But that can be easily resolved by creating a Child container and  using connect again . `connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(myChildComponent)`

i'd recommend go through this excellent article on [Smart Vs Dumb Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.bnbcq22sk) by Dan Abramov.